Proofs regarding spans - Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right"
I'm working through questions in the textbook "Linear Algebra Done Right", and I am currently on the topic of spans and linear independence. I'm relatively inexperienced with all the rigorous proofing that's involved in this subject, and I'd love some feedback on my answer to the following question about spans:

Suppose $_1,  \cdots , _$ is a list of vectors in $$. For $ ∈ \{1,  \cdots , \}$, let
$_ = _1 +  \cdots  + _$.
Show that $\operatorname{span}(_1,  \cdots , _) = \operatorname{span}(_1,  \cdots , _)$.

My Process:
First write out the spans individually:

$\operatorname{span}(v_1,  \cdots , v_m) = a_1v_1 +  \cdots  + a_mv_m$ for $ a_1,  \cdots , a_m \in \mathbf{F}$

$\operatorname{span}(w_1,  \cdots , w_m) = c_1w_1 +  \cdots  + c_1w_1$ for $ c_1,  \cdots , c_m \in \mathbf{F}$


Plug in $w_k = v_1 +  \cdots  + v_k$ to the second equation above, and notice that $v_1$ appears $k$ times with coefficients $c_1,  \cdots , c_m$, and that the next term appears $k-1$ times with coefficients $c_2,  \cdots , c_m$. This pattern continues until the $k$th  term, $v_m$, which appears exactly once in the expression with the coefficient $c_m$.
Allowing $a_k = c_k +  \cdots  + c_m$ where $k \in \{ 1,  \cdots , m-1 \} $ and letting $a_m = c_m$, we can write:
$$\operatorname{span}(w_1,  \cdots , w_m) = a_1v_1 +  \cdots  + a_mv_m = \operatorname{span}(v_1,  \cdots , v_m)$$
QED
Feedback for the validity and formatting of this proof would be greatly appreciated.

For solution verification (tag that I added), MSE's rules requires "the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so."

It's worth mentioning that you only show that $\operatorname{span}{w_i}{i=1}^m \subset \operatorname{span}{v_i}{i=1}^m$, not set equality. You have not shown that any set of $a_i$'s correspond to a set of $c_i$'s.

I think you have the core ideas, but a more explicit writing (especially of the relation of the $\sum c_i w_i$ to the $\sum a_i v_i$, and the defining properties of spans) would be nice. For instance, if you want to show $\operatorname{span}\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m = \operatorname{span}\{w_i\}_{i=1}^m$, then you really need  to work with the set-theoretic definition and hence show

$x \in \operatorname{span}\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m \implies x \in \operatorname{span}\{w_i\}_{i=1}^m$
$x \in \operatorname{span}\{w_i\}_{i=1}^m \implies x \in \operatorname{span}\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m$
$x \in \operatorname{span}\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m$ if you can find constants $a_i \in \mathbf{F}$ such that $x = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i v_i$. Similar for the $w$'s.

For instance, suppose $x \in \operatorname{span}\{w_i\}_{i=1}^m$, so we can find constants so that $x = \sum_{i=1}^m c_i w_i$. Then
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^m c_i w_i
= \sum_{i=1}^m c_i \left( \sum_{j=1}^i v_j \right)
= \sum_{i=1}^m  \sum_{j=1}^i  c_i v_j 
= \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=j}^m c_i v_j
= \sum_{j=1}^m \underbrace{\left( \sum_{i=j}^m c_i \right)}_{=a_i} v_j
$$
This expresses $x$ as a linear combination of the $v_j$, so it's in their span. (The key here is swapping the order of summation.) You can do similar for the other direction.

So from what I understand the part that I'm missing is that I need to prove the statement both ways, right?
I'm still a little confused about the last bullet point you wrote though, since don't solving the first two bullet points prove the statement already? I'm unsure of the purpose of the last bullet point.

The purpose of the last bullet is to show what it means to be an element of the span (i.e. the property you'd have to prove for each of the previous bullets)
